Leetcode 1482. Minimum Number of Days to Make m Bouquets: returning too many days
I am trying to solve LeetCode problem 1482. Minimum Number of Days to Make m Bouquets:

You are given an integer array bloomDay, an integer m and an integer k.
You want to make m bouquets. To make a bouquet, you need to use k adjacent flowers from the garden.
The garden consists of n flowers, the ith flower will bloom in the bloomDay[i] and then can be used in exactly one bouquet.
Return the minimum number of days you need to wait to be able to make m bouquets from the garden. If it is impossible to make m bouquets return -1.

I thought to use a binary search to determine the minimum number of days, by trying out each number visited in that binary search to see whether it is possible to achieve the target in that number of days.
This is my code:
   def minDays(self, bloomDay, m, k):
        """
        :type bloomDay: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type k: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        def possible(arr,day,m,k):
            count=0
            possible_b=0
            for i in range(len(arr)):
                if arr[i]<=day:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    possible_b+=count//k
                    count=0
            possible_b=count//k
            if possible_b>=m:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        low=1
        high=max(bloomDay)
        n=len(bloomDay)
        if k*m>n:
            return -1
        while low<=high:
            mid=(low+high)//2
            if possible(bloomDay,mid,m,k)==True:
                high=mid-1
            else:
                low=mid+1
        return low  

Problem
For the following test case my code returns the wrong answer:
bloomDay = [1,10,3,10,2], m = 3, k = 1

The expected output is 3, but my code returns 10.
What am I missing here?

The problem is in the function possible, at this line:
            possible_b=count//k

This overwrites the counts you had already accumulated in the loop.
Instead you should add them to what you already had:
            possible_b += count//k

This fix solves the problem.
Other remarks
Not related to your question, but:

Don't use an if...else block when you only want to return False or True based on a boolean expression. Just return the value of the boolean expression. So replace this:
          if possible_b>=m:
              return True
          else:
              return False

with this:
          return possible_b >= m


Don't compare a boolean expression with True or False. Just use the boolean expression itself. So change this:
if possible(bloomDay,mid,m,k)==True:

to this:
if possible(bloomDay,mid,m,k):


Don't use a loop over a range, when you really want to loop over the values of a sequence. So replace this:
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i]<=day:

with this:
for bloom in arr:
    if bloom <= day:



